# User-scoped settings lost after changed to 64-bit

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have developed a windows form application using C# using 32-bit version a long while along with user-scope settings `LastAccessedFileDateTime`. Now, I would indent to change that windows form application to 64-bit version.

Here, I have an issue that after changing 32-bit version to 64-bit version, my application didn't recognize my user-scope settings's (`LastAccessedFileDateTime`) current value.

**EDIT 1:**
I have tried to get current value using `Upgrade()` and `Reload()` functions in program startup as follows

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```

Still, I cannot able to get current value.